# No live media found when installing Ubuntu

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12 in to my desktop and once I insert the DVD in to my Rom the DVD ROM reads the disk but then it says "No live media found" I tried the same in my laptop it works perfectly.

Is there any problem in my DVD ROM?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it seems an issues with your DVD reader. Until you solve that issue you can try making iso from that ubuntu DVD, you said its works in laptop, so insert it in laptop make an iso image out of it, and then burn that iso image to usb drive. 
You can use brasero or k3b to make iso image from that DVD
Then you can use unetbootin as a gui way to burn the iso to pen drive or a you can type following command in terminal

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/iso/file.iso of=/dev/sdX
```

Where X is the name of your usb drive. Use dd command very carefully writing wrong device name can wipe out all your data. dd command first erases everything on the target device. To know the name of your usb drive run in terminal,

```
sudo fdisk -l
```